# Godot 4 point and move system offset even though all sprites are 0,0

Tags: godot4

I'm a rookie making my first 2d game in Godot, which I'm drafting from a much smaller JS,CSS, & HTML version called Storie. I am attempting to create a Point-click-and move function into my game.

All was well in my main sprites scene, but when I tried to use it in my game scene, there was a huge offset frome where I clicked and where the sprite went

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed = 400


var target = position

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("click"):
        target = get_global_mouse_position()

func _physics_process(_delta):
    velocity = position.direction_to(target) * speed
    # look_at(target)
    if position.distance_to(target) > 10:
        move_and_slide()
```

Oh, and also, I mistakenly switched to Godot 4 without realising the repercussions

Thank you, Dimitri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### About mixing coordinate systems

There are global coordinates, which are relative to the origin of the world. And there are local coordinates, which are relative to the parent node.

Now, `position` is local coordinates, so this is local coordinates:

```
var target = position
```

And this `get_global_mouse_position()` is global coordinates. Thus, this is global coordinates:

```
target = get_global_mouse_position()
```

Therefore, `target` is switching coordinates system. Once it has the global coordinates of the mouse position, then this is mixing coordinates system:

```
velocity = position.direction_to(target) * speed
```

Thus, the result will result in an incorrect behavior. The same happens here:

```
position.distance_to(target)
```

---

### Using global coordinates

You could convert to local coordinates (e.g. using `to_local`), however the `velocity` should be based on global coordinates (also `look_at`, we will get to that).

Thus, instead of using `position` which is in local coordinates, use `global_position` which is in global coordinates:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed = 400


var target = global_position

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("click"):
        target = get_global_mouse_position()

func _physics_process(_delta):
    velocity = global_position.direction_to(target) * speed
    # look_at(target)
    if global_position.distance_to(target) > 10:
        move_and_slide()
```

---

**Using `look_at`**

By the way, `look_at` also wants global coordinates.

Perhaps you want to move to inside the conditional (as there would be no direction to look at, if you are already at the position):

```
func _physics_process(_delta):
    velocity = global_position.direction_to(target) * speed
    if global_position.distance_to(target) > 10:
        look_at(target)
        move_and_slide()
```

---

### Properly avoid overshooting the target

You can compute how much the character would move.

Do you remember `speed` is distance over time?

Well, `delta` is the time. If `speed = distance / delta` and we solve for `distance` we have:

```
var distance = speed * delta
```

You could, for example, use in your check:

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    velocity = global_position.direction_to(target) * speed
    var distance := speed * delta
    if global_position.distance_to(target) > distance:
        look_at(target)
        move_and_slide()
```

However, I suggest you figure out which is the maximum speed the character can move this frame without overshooting the target:

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    var distance_to_target := global_position.distance_to(target)
    var direction_to_target := global_position.direction_to(target)
    var max_speed := distance_to_target / delta
    velocity = direction_to_target * clampf(speed, 0.0, max_speed)
    look_at(target)
    move_and_slide()
```

**Note**: `clampf(speed, 0.0, max_speed)` would be equivalent to `minf(speed, max_speed` assuming `speed` is positive to begin with. However, I believe `clampf(speed, 0.0, max_speed)` is more readable.

The above should stop at the target. However, if you want to have a check, use `is_zero_approx`:

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    var distance_to_target := global_position.distance_to(target)
    var direction_to_target := global_position.direction_to(target)
    if not is_zero_approx(distance_to_target):
        var max_speed := distance_to_target / delta
        velocity = direction_to_target  * clampf(speed, 0.0, max_speed)
        look_at(target)
        move_and_slide()
```

Comment: Thnx! I did confuse Global Position with normal positition
Sorry for answering late I took a loooooong break, im back now.